# SQL statement to find cost

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql results from a query that gives quantity left in inventory and its corresponding cost. e.g:

```
qty  cost
15.0 $2.50
20.0 $2.75
25.0 $3.00
```

I need to find the cost for a given quantity,

e.g. qty 15.0 and result would be:

```
qty  cost  total
15.0 $2.50  $37.50
```

e.g. qty 20.0 and result:

```
qty  cost  total
15.0 $2.50  $37.50
5.0  $2.75  $13.75
```

e.g qty 75.0 and result:
* when too many, use last cost value

```
qty  cost  total
15.0 $2.50  $37.50
20.0 $2.75  $55.00
25.0 $3.00  $75.00
15.0 $3.00  $45.00
```

how can i run in sql query statement?

Comment: what data types are qty and cost?

Comment: You need to get the combination of quantities that equals the given quality?
Are you sure that the total will fit?

Comment: @hazemtorab, lets first assume it fits, in some cases like the last example when the required qty is > the available then always use the last cost.

Comment: @ZoharPeled qty is decimal, cost is money

Comment: @Jackie this will not be done with single query, it can be done with cursors.. or loops.. is it ok with you?

Answer (score 2):

As simply as

```
SELEcT qty, cost, (qty * cost) AS total
```

You can do computations in your SELEcT clause as long as your columns are numeric